# Pass the whole grouped data frame to a function in summarise

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

With the new `summarise` from dplyr 1.0.0 it is possible to pass a function to summarise than returns a tibble

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  grp = rep(1:2, each = 5), 
  x = c(rnorm(5, -0.25, 1), rnorm(5, 0, 1.5)),
  y = c(rnorm(5, 0.25, 1), rnorm(5, 0, 0.5)),
)

quibble <- function(x, q = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) {
  tibble(x = quantile(x, q), q = q)
}

df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(quibble(x, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)))
```

I wonder whether it is possible to pass to the function inside `summarise` the whole grouped data frame instead of the names of the columns.
Something like

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(my_function(d))
```

where `d` is first `df` for `grp == 1` and then `df` for `grp == 2`.

I think that I know how to do it with `purrr::map`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(temp = map(data, my_function)) %>% 
  unnest(temp)
```

but I wonder whether it is possible to do it with `summarise`.

Comment: Can you use `.` as the placeholder for the full subset of `df`?

Comment: Please use set.seed to make the input reproducible and include all library statements. Also what is my_function and what is the expected output?

Comment: You may be able to use `cur_data()`.  Hard to know without a more concrete example.

Comment: @thelatemail The `.` pass the whole data frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tibble(gr=c(1,1,2), a=c(1,2,10), b=c(1,2,10)) %>% 
    print() %>% 
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      gr     a     b
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1
# 2     1     2     2
# 3     2    10    10
    group_by(gr) %>% 
    summarise(r=sum(cur_data()))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#      gr     r
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     6
# 2     2    20
```